# C#: Form containing OpenFileDialog. Both call ShowDialog(). Memory Leak?

Tags: winforms, memory-leaks

I have a form containing an OpenFileDialog added through the Visual Studio designer. I show the form using the following pattern:

```
using (var form = MyForm()) {
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then in the form I call

```
myOpenFileDialog.ShowModal();
```

Because the OpenFileDialog was added through the designer I can't use the using pattern above. Furthermore, in the Designer.cs file it doesn't appear that

```
myOpenFileDialog.Dispose();
```

is called. Do I have a memory leak here?

Comment: But doesn't a "leak" come when you cre

Comment: I would say a OpenFileDialogue doesn't need to be disposed so, no, you don't have a leak there.

Comment: Muaddib, I hope so :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no leak, but the `OpenFileDialog` will be disposed when the GC runs or the application went down. You can verify this by adding one function break point in visual studio for `System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose` since the `OpenFileDialog` is derived from `Component`.

So I think it's better to dispose it by yourself when you no longer need it.